# Error when trying to join elements in Jinja

Tags: python, jinja2

I have a list of items that I am trying to wrap inside of strong tags and separate by commas before having it rendered in my view.

Here's the line:

```
{% set exts = ', '.join("<strong>%s</strong>" ~ ext for ext in allowed_file_exts) %}
```

But unfortunately I receive the following error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got 'for'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need to set this comma-separated marked up list to a variable within the template instead of just displaying it (which is a lot easier...)?

Comment: @Wooble I actually display it later on in the view, I just didn't see that being necessary to include in my question since that's not where the error is happening.

Comment: Yes, I know, but do you have a reason to do it in 2 steps instead of assigning to a variable and then displaying?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the exact problem is, but there seems to be a problem with your list comprehension.

Please try this line instead:

```
{% set exts = ', '.join(["<strong>%s</strong>" % ext for ext in allowed_file_exts]) %}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "list comprehension" but you actually don't need brackets on the outside. Unfortunately your solution still causes Jinja to complain. Did you test before posting?

Comment: Maybe jinja requires the ~ instead of %. To answer your question, I don't have a jinja app running to test but this is probably the most likely diagnosis.